# Debug asynchron python script with vsc

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have module, which uses `from threading import Thread` and the code works totaly as expected, but I want to debug the module since I want expand the capabilites of the module. The Problem is following inside my `update` method, after the Thread has started, I am able to set Breakpoints, but I am unable to step forward, because the dubugger finishes without error message.

I am not completly shure, but from my pov it seems that the thread continues running in background, which makes the debugger struggle.

`subProcess` is enbaled in `launch.json`.

my minimal example:

```py
import sys
from threading import Thread

import cv2
from queue import Queue

class FileVideoStream:
    def __init__(self, path, queueSize=128):
        # initialize the file video stream along with the boolean
        # used to indicate if the thread should be stopped or not
        self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
        self.stopped = False

        # initialize the queue used to store frames read from
        # the video file
        self.forward_queue = Queue(maxsize=queueSize)

    def start(self):
        # start a thread to read frames from the file video stream
        thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()
        return self

    def update(self):
        # keep looping until stopped
        while not self.stopped:

            # otherwise, ensure the queue has room in it
            if not self.forward_queue.full():
                # read the next frame from the file
                (grabbed, frame) = self.stream.read()
                # if the `grabbed` boolean is `False`, then we have
                # reached the end of the video file
                if not grabbed:
                    self.stop()
                    return
                # add the frame to the queue
                self.forward_queue.put(frame)

    def stop(self):
        self.stopped = True

def main():
    video = sys.argv[1]
    fvs = FileVideoStream(video)
    fvs.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

my launch file for the minimal:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: minimal",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "minimal.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [".\\test\\test_biqueue.mp4"],
            "subProcess": true
        }
    ]
}
```

My Breakpoints are at line 20 (this one works at expected) and at line 30 (here the weird asynchron stuff is happening).

The Argument test_biqueue.mp4 could be any arbitrary video file.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example incl. launch settings and breakpoints!

Comment: how to include breakpopints?

Comment: Just name the file and line number.